# Determine whether $\frac{\sqrt{-23}+\sqrt[23]{-2}}{2}$ is an algebraic integer.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

An algebraic integer is an algebraic number that is a root of some monic polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$.

When I check that $\frac{\sqrt{-23}+\sqrt[23]{-2}}{2}$ is an algebraic integer or not by WolframAlpha, the result is false. But I can not prove it. I try to find the minimal polynomial of that element. But it does not seem to work. I mean $23$ is big and difficult to do it by hand. Is there any quicker way to check it?

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to compute the norm in some clever way? It is not hard to find all the conjugates of the number, and there should be an easy way to multiply all of them.

Comment: I don't think it is easy to compute directly the norm of that element but I think it can be another way to check. Thank you for your suggestion! :)

Comment: Wolfram Alpha tells me the minimal polynomial is $70368744177664 x^{46} + $ ... um, I don't feel like typing all that. Do you get a similar result?

Comment: You can instantaneously see that the number (call it $\alpha$) is not an integer because the numerator is "odd" while the denominator is "even." More precisely, if $v$ is any $2$-adic valuation, then $v(\sqrt{-23}) = 0$ and $v(\sqrt[23]{-2}) \ne 0$, so the numerator is a $2$-adic unit with respect to $v$ and not divisible by $2$.

Answer (score 10):

Let's call your number $\alpha$. Because $-23\equiv1\pmod4$ it is well known that $\beta=(1+\sqrt{-23})/2$ is an algebraic integer. Because algebraic integers form a ring, $\alpha$ is one if and only if
$$
\gamma=\alpha-\beta=\frac{-1+\root{23}\of{-2}}2
$$
is an algebraic integer.

Eisenstein's criterion gives that the polynomial $x^{23}+2$ is irreducible, so $$[\Bbb{Q}(\gamma):\Bbb{Q}]=[\Bbb{Q}(\root{23}\of{-2}):\Bbb{Q}]=23.$$ Therefore the minimal polynomial $m(x)$ of $\gamma$ has degree $23$.
Clearly, $(2\gamma+1)^{23}+2=0$, so (scaling to make the polynomial monic)
$$
m(x)=\frac1{2^{23}}\left((2x+1)^{23}+2\right).
$$
The constant term $m(0)=3/2^{23}$ is manifestly not a rational integer, so $\gamma$ is not an algberaic integer. Therefore neither is $\alpha$.

Comment: I guess that after shifting the focus from $\alpha$ to $\gamma$ almost any method will work. For example, it should be possible to compute the norm. Well, that's what I did in a way :-)

Comment: It's great :)) I think it is one of the best ways. Thank you so much!

Comment: +1 moral of the lesson: You don't need to fully write down a minimal polynomial to work with the minimal polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt{-23}$ is a root of the polynomial $x^2 + 23$, so $\sqrt{-23}/2$ is a root of $(2x)^2 + 23 = 4 x^2 + 23$ and thus of $x^2 + 23/4$.  Thus it is an eigenvalue of the companion matrix 
$$ A = \pmatrix{0 & -23/4\cr 1 & 0\cr}$$
of $x^2 + 23/4$.
$\sqrt[23]{-2}$ is a root of $x^{23}+2$, and $\sqrt[23]{-2}/2$ is a root of $x^{23} + 2/2^{23} = x^{23} + 2^{-22}$ and an eigenvalue of 
the $23 \times 23$ companion matrix with $1$ on the first subdiagonal, 
$2^{-22}$ in position $(1,23)$, and $0$ elsewhere.  Thus
their sum is an eigenvalue of $A \otimes I + I \otimes B$, a $46 \times 46$ matrix.  The characteristic polynomial of this is an irreducible (according to Maple) monic polynomial of degree $46$ which has non-integer coefficients.  Thus your number is not an algebraic integer.

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)))